# WordPress Network install error

Tags: wordpress, multisite

Reinstalling wordpress multisite

`Warning: an existing wordpress network was detected.`

I tried multiple solutions including dropping tables, resetting .htaccess and completely resetting wp_config. It installs fine the first time but when I log out and log in I get this error.

Comment: please mention your tried solutions in question to help better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38755236/enable-wordpress-multi-site-network-enabled#:%7E:text=I%20moved%20the%20following%20lines%20from%20wp%2Dconfig.php%20to%20the%20bottom%20of%20the%20file%20and%20then%20it%20started%20working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the steps in this order

1) Reset your wp-config.php file back to its original state, remove any MULTISITE references

2) Delete the .htaccess file or move it temporarily

3) Drop the following tables from your DB, use a tool like phpMyAdmin if you are not comfortable directly modifying table data

- wp_blogs
- wp_blog_versions
- wp_registration_log
- wp_site
- wp_sitemeta
- wp_signups
- wp_sitecategories

4) Log out and Log back into your site and initiate the Network Setup.

5) Recreate the .htaccess file with the copy pasted data

6) Modify the wp-config.php file, remember to paste those lines above the line where it says

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

Step 6 is important see below :

http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/multisite-not-working-warning-an-existing-wordpress-network-was-detected

Also read :

http://blog.ashfame.com/2010/07/remove-wordpress-multisite-data/

Comment: I have done all of this... three times, and still get the same message. Any other tips?

Answer (score 2):

WordPress version: 5.4.2

The documentation to install WordPress multi-site needs revision. The instructions say to add these two lines. Adding both of these lines doesn't activate the multi-site:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
```

Instead, just using the following line and it works:

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps anyone else, I was experiencing this error after I forget to manually clear my OpCache after making the changes to wp-config.php, so the database indicated a multisite network but wp-config did not reflect it. Clearing the OpCache fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After hundreds of attempts, what worked for me was to add the code from wp_config.php to the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the code is put before the line

```
/* That’s all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

and that the following 2 lines are after this comment

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
        define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

resource [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38755236/enable-wordpress-multi-site-network-enabled#:%7E:text=I%20moved%20the%20following%20lines%20from%20wp%2Dconfig.php%20to%20the%20bottom%20of%20the%20file%20and%20then%20it%20started%20working)