# Enable Wordpress Multi site (Network enabled)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, multisite

I'm trying to activate multi-site in wordpress version 4.5.3 but keep getting the error message: `Warning: An existing WordPress network was detected.
Please complete the configuration steps. To create a new network, you will need to empty or remove the network database tables.`

I've deleted the tables and columns added by multi-site using the below:

```
drop table wp_blogs;
drop table wp_blog_versions;
drop table wp_registration_log;
drop table wp_site;
drop table wp_sitemeta;
drop table wp_signups;
alter table wp_users drop column spam;
alter table wp_users drop column deleted;
```

I've removed the following lines from `/var/app/current/wp-config.php`:

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'site.tld');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

I've restored the original `.htaccess` file (from a back up and from re-generating using `Settings -> Permalinks`) so it looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

When I navigate to the Network Setup I'm greeted with the `Create a Network of WordPress Sites` page where I select Sub-domains and click Install.

There is no error on the following set up page, **however** if I refresh or navigate back to this page in any way I see the error at the top, regardless of whether or not I have applied the changes requested.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved the following lines from `wp-config.php` to the bottom of the file and then it started working

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
        define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

If someone can let me know why this fixed it I will be very grateful, because it makes no sense why this would fix anything.

Comment: This was here for me by default. So i guess it should be there by default?

Comment: Thanks you so much, save my day