# Cannot fix wordpress multisite issue because don't have htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx

Since Nginx doesn't support htaccess, i am unable to fix this issue.

Currently i am following this guide:
[WordPress Network install error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988719/wordpress-network-install-error)

Is there any solution for this?

**UPDATE:** I found a solution for converting htaccess to nginx conf format. Now i don't know where to put this code.

**SOLUTION:** 
Nginx Configuration is located on
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site1.com
If you got error when restarting nginx service, try this  sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t So you can track down syntax that cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx Configuration is located on

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site1.com
```

If you got error when restarting nginx service, try this 
`sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t`
So you can track down syntax that cause the error.